# avformat_open_input returns -48

Tags: ffmpeg, libavcodec, libavformat

On macOS `avformat_open_input` sometimes returns the error code `-48`:

```
avformat_open_input(&ctx, "udp://...", NULL, NULL);
```

I cannot find this error code in the AVERROR code list. What does this error code mean?

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FFmpeg error codes are usually the standard C error codes negated. So error code 48 looks like `ELNRNG (Link number out of range)`. But something fishy, I never see FFmpeg returns this error before.

Update:
`av_strerror()` function does the human-readable conversions, here:
https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavu__error.html#ga5792b4a2d18d7d9cb0efbcfc335dce24

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The software using the function is installed on 1000s of machines but the error occurs only on a single machine. Probably the machine is somehow malconfigured.